# delete part of string with different format

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 strings in 2 tables with the same text but with different formats. Moreover, in table 2 the data is concatenated as the user enters new info. Is there a way to delete from the concatenated text the data coming from table 1? So the delete is performed on table 2 based on info from table 1. I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Table 1

```
12/01 aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Table 2

```
10/01 Sfdfdg 12/01 aaa bbb ccc  14/02 sdgdfgfh
```

Comment: *"in table 2 the data is concatenated as the user enters new info"* It's time to think about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Cid, I totally agree with you but the client doesn't want that.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. The strings in those two are not the same at all. And it is not clear what you want as output. And seriously....you need to fix the architecture.

Comment: I understand what you're wanting to do (a delete using a join) but the sample data doesn't illustrate the issue very well, so it's difficult to try and provide a useful answer.